# Update is not working in Google Prediction Java API v1.6

Tags: google-prediction

I have created an empty model in google prediction api by using prediction.trainedmodels.insert . I provided empty stored location and training instances. It has created successfully.

Now I am trying to update the model with new training instances using Google Prediction Java API 1.6 .

Here is  code

```
    public class PredictionSample {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "MyApplication";

    static final String MODEL_ID = "3";
    static final String STORAGE_DATA_LOCATION = "";


     private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
     new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/prediction_sample");


     private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;


     private static HttpTransport httpTransport;


     private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

      private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {

      GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
      new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("client_secrets.json"))));

     GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
    Collections.singleton(PredictionScopes.PREDICTION)).setDataStoreFactory(
    dataStoreFactory).build();

   return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
   }

   private static void run() throws Exception {
   httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
   dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
   // authorization
   Credential credential = authorize();
    Prediction prediction = new Prediction.Builder(
    httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    update(prediction);
     predict(prediction, "Camera is bad");
     predict(prediction, "Camera is good");
     predict(prediction, "Camera is awesome");
    }

  private static void update(Prediction prediction) throws IOException {
  Update  update  = new Update();
  List<Object> csvInstance = new ArrayList<Object>();
  csvInstance.add("camera is awesone");
  update.setCsvInstance(csvInstance);
  update.setOutput("postive");

   prediction.trainedmodels().update("<project-no>" , MODEL_ID, update).execute();

   System.out.println("Update started.");
    System.out.print("Waiting for update to complete");
    System.out.flush();


    int triesCounter = 0;
    while (triesCounter < 100) {

    try {
    HttpResponse response = prediction.trainedmodels().get("<project-no>",   
    MODEL_ID).executeUnparsed();
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {

      System.out.println(response.getStatusMessage());

      return;
                }
    response.ignore();
  } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
  }

  try {

    Thread.sleep(1000 * (triesCounter + 1));
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    break;
  }
  System.out.print(".");
  System.out.flush();
  triesCounter++;
}


   }

     private static void predict(Prediction prediction, String text) throws IOException {
      Input input = new Input();
      InputInput inputInput = new InputInput();
       inputInput.setCsvInstance(Collections.<Object>singletonList(text));
       input.setInput(inputInput);
         Output output = 
        prediction.trainedmodels().predict("<project-no>", MODEL_ID,      input).execute();
         System.out.println("Text: " + text);
        System.out.println("Predicted language: " + output.getOutputLabel());
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
     run();
     // success!
      return;
      } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      } catch (Throwable t) {
       t.printStackTrace();
     }
     System.exit(1);
   }
   }
```

This code give following output.

```
 Update  started.
 Waiting for Update to complete
 OK
 400 Bad Request
 {
   "code" : 400,
   "errors" : [ {
   "domain" : "global",
   "location" : "q",
   "locationType" : "parameter",
   "message" : "Model is empty. Please update it first.",
   "reason" : "invalidQuery"
   } ],
  "message" : "Model is empty. Please update it first."
   }
```

When I am getting OK and status code 200 while updating the model ,why it's saying model is empty . Please help me on the same.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this? I am having the same problem

Comment: Same here. Ever solve this?